# build(),copy() & setHelpText are being left off of the TextValidationBuilder auto complete drop down

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I wanted to learn a little more about Google Forms so I did this little form and as I was adding text validation to the the textItems which are meant to contain a URL and an Email I noticed that some of the things I expected to see in the code completion drop downs were not available.  So I tried running without them and kept on getting errors like "cannot find setValidation(TextValidationBuilder)".

```
function createSimpleForm()
{
   var linkValidation=FormApp.createTextValidation().requireTextIsUrl();
   var emailValidation=FormApp.createTextValidation().requireTextIsEmail();
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var form=FormApp.create('Google Apps Script Question');
   form.setDescription('A Simple Form to display my script editing problem.')
       .setConfirmationMessage('Thanks.  I\'ll be getting back to you at your email.')
       .setAllowResponseEdits(true)
       .setAcceptingResponses(false)
       .setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
   var containerLink=form.addTextItem();
   containerLink.setTitle('Enter a URL')
       .setValidation(linkValidation);
   var clientEmail=form.addTextItem();
   clientEmail.setTitle('Enter an email address')
      .setValidation(emailValidation)
      .isRequired();
}
```

Then I noticed that only the build() command returns a TextValidation object and that's what the parameter for setValidation needs

[image]

So at that point I decided to stick the commands that I thought belong there and finished with a build() and code runs with no errors.

```
function createSimpleForm()
{
   var linkValidation=FormApp.createTextValidation().setHelpText('This must be a URL.').requireTextIsUrl().build();
   var emailValidation=FormApp.createTextValidation().setHelpText('This must be a EMail.').requireTextIsEmail().build();
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var form=FormApp.create('Google Apps Script Question');
   form.setDescription('A Simple Form to display my script editing problem.')
       .setConfirmationMessage('Thanks.  I\'ll be getting back to you at your email.')
       .setAllowResponseEdits(true)
       .setAcceptingResponses(false)
       .setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
   var containerLink=form.addTextItem();
   containerLink.setTitle('Enter a URL')
       .setValidation(linkValidation);
   var clientEmail=form.addTextItem();
   clientEmail.setTitle('Enter an email address')
      .setValidation(emailValidation)
      .isRequired();
}
```

I tried shutting down my browser and returning to the script editor but it doesn't seem to make any difference the same methods still missing from content assist.  **I'm wondering if any one else has had the same problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the methods `build`, `copy`, and `setHelpText` are missing from the autocomplete on TextValidationBuilder objects. You may want to report this on the [Apps Script issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/566222).

Documentation is more reliable than the editor, so when in doubt, go with what documentation says. The autocomplete is flawed in other ways; for example, on the array objects it misses such basic methods as `indexOf`, `map`, `filter`, and `reduce`.